# Make menu stick for mobile visitors?

Tags: css, menu, prestashop

I'm running Prestashop e-commerce at (link was removed due to canceled project)

If you look at the page from a mobile phone and select "VALJ DIN MODELL HAR" in the menu the page reloads.

Any clue why? I works fine from mac and windows.

My thoughts is some kind of hoover issue since i cant hoover on a smart phone?

Answer (score 0):

You are right, hover is the problem. You can't hover with a smartphone. I used in my last project sidr for mobile phones: http://www.berriart.com/sidr/

Answer (score 0):

In your site http://mobilprylar.nu, link is already offered for `VALJ DIN MODELL HAR` category. If you click on it you'll be redirected to `VALJ DIN MODELL HAR` category page. This is fine for desktop view as we have hover/mouseover functionality.

This will not work for mobile phones because once you click on it, both hover and link will be active so you'll never get better result.

I would recommend you to disable the link for mobile view, we have javascript functionality available for this. Else, if you are good enough in prestashop/smarty coding you can create  separate menu for mobile view. Hope this helps.